# How to separate upper and lower case with counter?

Tags: python

I am thinking of something with collections

```
s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
import collections
c = collections.Counter(s)
```

As a result I have

```
Counter({' ': 8,
         ',': 1,
         '.': 1,
         '?': 1,
         'H': 1,
         'M': 1,
         'R': 1,
         'T': 1,
         'a': 2,
         'd': 1,
         'e': 5,
         'f': 1,
         'g': 1,
         'h': 2,
         'i': 2,
         'l': 2,
         'n': 1,
         'o': 4,
         'r': 3,
         's': 3,
         't': 1,
         'u': 2,
         'w': 1,
         'y': 2})
```

If I try sum I got syntax problem

```
print sum(1 for i in c if i.isupper())

File "<ipython-input-21-66a7538534ee>", line 4
    print sum(1 for i in c if i.isupper())
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How should I count only upper or lower from the counter?

Comment: Isn't it obvious from your example that you need to feed to the counter only the fact that a letter is uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes but how?MY sum does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack the `()` in your generator expresion:

```
sum((1 for x in c if x.isupper()))
4
```

EDIT: As @Błotosmętek sugest, you lack the `()` in your print, i guess you are using python3, you should use `print()`

Comment: Judging from the position of error, he lacks () in his `print` function call - apparently he is using Python 3.x and so it should be: `print(sum(1 for x in c if x.isupper()))` (and anyway, @Nurzhan's answer is probably what the OP really wanted)

Comment: @DanielSanchez Yes,I am using Python 3

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
import collections

s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
c = collections.Counter([ch for ch in s if ch.isupper()])
# Change to ch.islower() if you need lower case
# c = collections.Counter([ch for ch in s if ch.islower()])
print(c)
```